# American Swaption Heding with Malliavin Calculus

Tags: hedging, american-options, swaption, malliavin-calculus

Hedging American Swaption

Hello, I priced an American swaption using Black model with swap rates diffusion to find the european (call) price at t.

$$ C_t = (\delta \sum_{j=n+1}^{M+1} Z_t^{T_j})[R(t,T_n,T_m)  - \hat{R}]^{+} $$

$$ dR(t,T_n,T_M) =  \sigma R(t,T_n,T_M) dW_t $$

Then I found the early exercice boundary via MC Simulation, with this method.

[PRICING AMERICAN OPTIONS USING MONTE CARLO SIMULATION](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~s0237075/projectm3s/projectm3s.pdf)

The choice of this method rely on the need to have an explicit criterion for the optimal exercise, and because I had to add a depreciaton factor on the the principal amount (contract linked to a loan).

As you may know, it is not very interesting to compute greeks with finite difference of a Mc Price.

Now I want to hedge this american swaption, so I am trying to calculate the $\Delta$ of the contract.

I know that Malliavin calculus can give good results in this domain, but I can't find any paper for the implementation of the method for an american swaption.

I found this paper for american option, but I am not sure to be able to adapt it.

[Applications of Malliavin calculus to the pricing
and hedging of Bermudan options](http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/1381/1/J_Newbury.pdf)

Do you think this approach could be generalised to American Swaption ? 
What would be your approach to hedging an American Swaption ?

Comment: Could you define delta, Z and R^hat, please?

Comment: $\Delta$ is the derivative of the value with respect to the underlying R, Z is the Bdiscount factor, $\hat{R}$ is the strike rate.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the other delta in front of the summation sigma in C. It might be just a constant? Hm, maybe it is not a delta at all... So the hat does not denote some kind of averaging but R^hat is simply a constant, correct?

Comment: Yes this is a constant representing one cash flows. 1/Tenor if we took an amount of 1 or K/Tenor if we took an amount K.